# How to register a custom callback after Ember.RSVP.hash

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

I have a route that pulls in 2 different promises using RSVP like so

```
model: function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash(function() {
    stuff: App.Thing.find(),
    other: this.store.find('appointments', {day: day})    
  });
}
```

The challenge is that I have a custom function I bind/invoke in the "then" of the 2nd promise shown above. How can I invoke this when the callback happens along side another promise using RSVP?

Here is the custom callback as it stands today (not inside of RSVP.hash just yet)

```
    function bindContextAndGenerateAvailable(employee, other, appointments) {
        return function(filteredAppointments) {
            //will take the filtered collection and do something w/ it
            //to populate the bound appointments array passed in
        }
    }

    var appointments = Ember.A([]);
    this.store.find('appointment', {day: day}).then(function(response) {
        Ember.RSVP.all(response.getEach('employee')).then(function(empls){
          var filtered = response.filterBy('employee.id', employee);
          Ember.RSVP.resolve(filtered).then(bindContextAndGenerateAvailable(employee, other, appointments));
        });
    });
    return appointments;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure if I completely understand, but I'm going to take a stab at it, and if I'm wrong I'll just quickly edit as you say my guessing is wrong.

Promises are super awesome when you do chaining of them (`.then`).  Let me see if I can do some quick examples and see if this applies to what you're doing.

#### Chaining returns the last result.

```
var foo = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
  resolve(1);
}).then(function(result){
  return result + 2;
});

foo.then(function(result){
  alert(result); // this will alert 3, not 1
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/levoyama/1/edit

#### Chaining returns the deepest result.  If you return a promise as the result of the then, it waits on that to resolve, and returns the result of it.  Quick note: cast is a quick way to cast anything into a `promise`, making it thenable.

```
var bar = Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(1).then(function(result){
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
    resolve(2 + result);
  });
});

bar.then(function(result){
  alert(result); // this will alert 3, not 1
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/voxevucu/1/edit

#### Hash taking the latest and greatest

Hash is going to take the deepest/last result of any promise sent to it, and use the result of that in its resultant hash.  In the example below, both promise 1 and promise 2 will result in 5, despite their initial promise values being 1/2.

```
var promise1 = Em.RSVP.Promise.cast(1)
                 .then(function(result){ return result + 1; })
                 .then(function(result){ return result + 1; })
                 .then(function(result){ return result + 1; })
                 .then(function(result){ return result + 1; });

var promise2 = Em.RSVP.Promise.cast(2)
                 .then(function(result){
                  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
                    resolve(result + 3);
                  });
                 });
           

var hash = Em.RSVP.hash({
   p1: promise1,
   p2: promise2
});

hash.then(function(result){
  alert(result.p1 + ' + ' + result.p2 + ' = ' + (result.p1 + result.p2) + ', alert the presses!!!!');
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vevaruta/1/edit

#### Sharing promises/multiple observers

I reread the question and have another guess.  Promises can have infinite number of observes that will all fire when the promise is resolved, if you need to use a promise for two different purposes.

```
var promise1 = Em.RSVP.Promise.cast('of warcraft');

promise1.then(function(result){
  alert('hello world ' + result);
});

promise1.then(function(result){
  alert('stop playing world ' + result);
});

Em.RSVP.hash({
  p: promise1
}).then(function(hash){
  alert('hash result p is: ' + hash.p);
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sovolibo/1/edit

In the scenario where you want the result (for the model) to be  modified after both promises were resolved you would do something like this.

```
model: function(){
  var promise1 = Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(1);
  var promise2 = Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(2);

  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    p1 = promise1,
    p2 = promise2
  }).then(function(result){
      return result.p1 + result.p2;
  });
}
```

The result of the model ends up being 3, not a hash, cause we did some post processing with the resultant of the hash.

But if you want to do something async, as in it doesn't matter for the model's sake, it would be something like this:

```
model: function(){
  var promise1 = Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(1);
  var promise2 = Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(2);

  var hash = Ember.RSVP.hash({
    p1 = promise1,
    p2 = promise2
  });
  
  var randomPromise = hash.then(function(result){
    return result.p1 + result.p2;
  });

  randomPromise.then(function(result){
    alert(result);
  });

  return hash;
}
```

In this scenario, the model hook needs the hash, but then you want to do something different with the results when it's finished, and the model hook doesn't need to wait on the random promise after the fact.

Comment: Wow -what a reply! I think the last reply you had is closer to what I want in this scenario. Just to clarify - in the example I have, could I use the hash w/ 2 promises in side it. implement my bind method in the "then" callback (right on the hash itself like you showed in the last line of code) ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is *extrememly* helpful. I simply want to chime in with an alternate example for resolving:

```
var promise, colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];

promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  // timeouts below mimic a webservice response with new data
  setTimeout(function() {
    colors.pushObject('orange');
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    colors.pushObject('green');
  }, 2000);

  Ember.run.later(colors, function() {
    colors.pushObject('pink');
  }, 3000);

  resolve(colors);
});

return promise;
```

This would immediately render the values 'red', 'yellow' and 'blue' and over the next three seconds render 'orange', then 'green', and finally 'pink'. Hopefully this isn't too redundant.

Comment: Hi Tom, the use of the promise here isn't actually necessary, you can just return colors, and modify the collection after the fact asynchronously.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cozezi/1/edit

Comment: You're absolutely right, Kingpin2k. My example is _completely contrived_. I was just trying to document a use case similar to how you might use a Deferred and resolve/reject it based on loading other data. I'm new-er to EmberJS and have more of a background in Backbone and Angular, and while trying to figure out how to do this in Ember, it seemed as if their Deferred method was deprecated. This was my solution to handling that. I just wanted to throw it out there for others that may be wandering around too. Please let me know if there's a better way. :)

Comment: Looking at this again, it probably would have been a more accurate example to resolve in the `setTimeout` with a different array.

Comment: Yeah, that would make more sense, if you wanted to stall the model hook from resolving until all of them are resolved.